# How to use the Wordpress < LinkControl /> Component

Tags: block-editor

## The issue

I am looking for a way to **add linking functionality to a custom block** of mine and found different approaches to this need.

There are:

1. The [URLInputButton Component](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/url-input#urlinputbutton)
2. The [URLInput Component](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/url-input#urlinput)
3. The [LinkControl Component](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/link-control)
4. The [URLPopover Component](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/73eaacb2e39bc05f520ab65d470512b365efb635/packages/block-editor/src/components/url-popover/README.md)

I got it somehow working with the first two components:

```
const {URLInputButton, URLInput, URLPopover} = wp.blockEditor;

registerBlockType('my-plugin-domain/textlink', {
    title: __('Text Link', 'my-textdomain'),
    
    ...

    attributes: {
        url: {
            type: 'string',
        },
    },

    edit(props) {

        const {
            attributes,
            setAttributes,
        } = props;

        const {url} = attributes;

        const blockControls = (
            !!isSelected && (
                <BlockControls>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <URLInputButton
                            url={url}
                            onChange={(url, post) => setAttributes(
                                    {url, title: (post && post.title) || __('Click here')},
                                )}
                            />

                        <URLInput
                            className={className}
                            value={url}
                            onChange={(url, post) => setAttributes(
                                    {url, text: (post && post.title) || 'Click here'})}
                            />
                    </Toolbar>

    }
    ...


});
```

Unfortunately the `URLInput` as well as the `URLInputButton` appear **displaced/buggy** when entering a link.

Hence I'm trying to figure out a way how to use the `LinkControl` Component and I can't get it to work. I wasn't even able to figure out from which Package it has to be imported yet.

```
const {LinkControl} = wp.blockEditor; // This doesn't seem to work 


const {LinkControl} = wp.components; // Neither this

...

// This is not working:

edit(props){
 ...
 <LinkControl
    onChange={(nextValue) => {
    console.log(nextValue);
    }}
 />
...
}

...
```

Also I wasn't able to get the [URLPopover](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/73eaacb2e39bc05f520ab65d470512b365efb635/packages/block-editor/src/components/url-popover/README.md) to work.

If anyone could point me into the right direction, it would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Would it not make more sense to add a richtext component so that it automatically pulls in formats instead of rebuilding the format system from scratch?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion! Yeah I actually thought about that too of course. In context of a specific CTA component, however it was more plausible to me to build it rather from scratch.

Comment: Refer: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/block-editor/src/components/link-control

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*LinkControl* is an experimental component, so it's declared differently in *blockEditor* package

try this as an import statement, this worked for me:

```
const {__experimentalLinkControl } = wp.blockEditor;
const LinkControl = __experimentalLinkControl;
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Comment: @fluoriteen thank you very much. I didn't expect the LinkControl to still be experimental. Even though I like Cláudio Esperança's approach of an aliased destructured variable - you pointed me to the right direction, which is why I will mark your answer as the solution. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, sorry not that strong into ES6 / React syntax - I like Cláudio Esperança's approach as well, will update my code :)

Answer (score 6):

Follow up on @fluoriteen answer: you can use aliased destructured variable assignment to have an one line assignment:

```
const {__experimentalLinkControl: LinkControl} = wp.blockEditor;
```

Answer (score 4):

And for consistency with the other answers, if your using `@wordpress/scripts` webpack build routines you'd simply do

```js
import {
    __experimentalLinkControl as LinkControl
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';
```

Comment: It's better to use `@wordpress/scripts` and `@wordpress/block-editor` so you can have autocomplete in your IDE.